# C++ How to create a function writing data in file for multiple use with different names

Tags: c++

I have some data in an array which is manipulated in about five or six steps. After each step I want the program to write a file with the manipulated data. This is the working code for that:

```
ofstream mirroreddata("mirroreddata.dat", ios::out);   
for (int i = 0; i < n_values; i++)
{
    mirroreddata << datavector[i] << "\n";     
}
mirroreddata << endl;                                  
mirroreddata.close();
```

The problem is, that I don't want to write this thing multiple times. I want to create a function I just have to call with the name of the file (here: mirroreddata) and n_values and the datavector. Giving the function the datavector and n_values is no problem, but how to tell her writing the data in a new file? This is the code fragment for this but it is not right:

```
void CreateDataOutputFile(int n_values, double* datavector)
{
    ofstream mirroreddata("mirroreddata.dat", ios::out);                                                    
    for (int i = 0; i < n_values; i++)
    {
        mirroreddata << datavector[i] << "\n";      
    }
    mirroreddata << endl;                               
}
```

So how to call this but writing data in a new file (for example the smoothed data in file "smoothed")?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Pass another parameter for the filename?

Answer (score 0):

Easy: add another parameter for the filename:

```
#include <string>

void CreateDataOutputFile(int n_values, double* datavector, const std::string& fname)
{
    ofstream mirroreddata(fname, ios::out);                                                    
    for (int i = 0; i < n_values; i++)
    {
        mirroreddata << datavector[i] << "\n";      
    }
    mirroreddata << endl;                               
}
```